# ConfirmButtonExtender doesn't cancel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I inserted this confirm button extender into my webpage. I have 2 option that is ok and cancel. When i clicked okay, it updates my database. But when i clicked cancel and also updates my database.

```
<asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="btnClear_ConfirmButtonExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnClear"
ConfirmText="Are you sure you would like to update the following police report? The page will automatically refreshes if the report has been updated successfully"
OnClientCancel="CancelClick" />
```

I didnt enter any codes in my back-end side. So i guess the problem lies with the source code.

Source Link : [ConfirmButtonExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx)

Comment: So how did you define `CancelClick`?

Comment: I'm not very sure either. i took the codes from the asp.net websites.

Comment: Share the code please, only then we can tell you where you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the `OnClientCancel="CancelClick"` and add `Enabled="true"`.
It should work.

Comment: The online property list (linked in the question) does not show anything called `Enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `OnClientCancel` specifies a javascript function to call not server side method.  Instead of the code you have for `CancelClick`, use this as a test in your HTML markup to see it in action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CancelClick()
    {
        alert('called by javascript');
    }
</script>
```

Now check that `cancel` button is still Updating or will show you the `called by javascript` message on alert.

Hope it clear and works for you.